# Merging 2 sheets based on 1 column

Tags: excel

I have two sheets which are in one Excel file.

1. Sheet1 has style numbers with quantities
2. Sheet2 has style numbers with different quantities.

Most of the style numbers match in both sheets (and they are both sorted alpha) but there are some styles that exist in one sheet and not the other and vice versa.

What is the best way to automatically merge the 2 sheets based on style number, and then add the rows from sheet1 that are not found in sheet 2 as well?

Is it with a `vlookup`? I know I can use `vlookup` but then the columns that are not a match in both sheets won't be copied over and I won't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 2 `VLOOKUP`s, one to get the data from `sheet2`, and one in `sheet2` to identify the numbers not found in `sheet1` (by putting a filter on all the cells that return `#N/A`).

Comment: why does this vlookup seem to not work =VLOOKUP(D4,Sheet1!$A$3:$M$27,4)

D4= 1009SA
sheet1 B3 = 1009SA
sheet1 column 4 on the 1009SA line is 1

Instead of returning 1 it returns #N/A

Comment: You need to align the lookup values. If your lookup value is in column B of sheet one (given by your example), you should adjust your vlookup formula to `=VLOOKUP(D4,Sheet1!$B$3:$M$27,4)`.